# Plotly Dash : Remove default white graph background

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

One of the graphs in my dash application is rendered upon an button click event from the callback.

I'd like to remove the default white background of the graph when the page is loaded. It kinda looks odd for my layout. Is this possible?

[image]

I have already tried the following with no success.

```
layout=go.Layout(

                annotations=[{'text': str(score) + "%", 'x':0.5, 'y':0.5, 'font_size':35, 'showarrow':False}],
                paper_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                plot_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                showlegend=False
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use update_layout. That's just how plotly tells us to build dash apps in its tutorial. You can read more about that in the second link below.

Second, plotly offers a dark theme template that makes life easy. But you can also do RGB hex, which you can check out in both the links below.

```
fig = go.Figure(
data=go.Surface(z=z_data.values),
layout=go.Layout(
    title="Mt Bruno Elevation",
    width=500,
    height=500,
))

fig.update_layout(template=""plotly_dark", title="Mt Bruno Elevation: '%s' theme" % template)
fig.show()
```

https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-paper_bgcolor
https://dash.plotly.com/layout